# Storing MySQL Database connections in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

When reviewing some of my existing code, I realized that I was constantly opening and close remote DB connections to pull information about hundreds of devices. I am now trying to resolve this by storing the database connections in an array and checking if the particular connection already exists by name before creating it.

```
$mysql_connections = array();

$devices = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM devices ORDER BY name ASC", $dp_conn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($devices))
{
    $whmcs_site = $row['whmcs_site'];
    $whmcs_id = $row['whmcs_id'];

    /* WHMCS Service */
    if ($whmcs_site != "" && $whmcs_id != "")
    {
        $site = get_site_details($whmcs_site, $dp_conn);

        if (in_array($site['name'], $mysql_connections))
        {
            echo "Connection already exists</br>";
            $whmcs = $mysql_connections[$site['name']];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No connection exists...creating it named" . $site['name'] . " </br>";

            $whmcs = whmcs_connect($site);
            $mysql_connections[$site['name']] = $whmcs;
        }
```

There are only 2 possible MySQL Databases so the in_array() check should be returning true after it stores both of them. For some reason it never finds the existing entries though so it continues to just spawn new connections on every iteration. Can anyone point out what the issue is here?

Comment: Have you made any debugging attempts at all?  Where does code execution vary from what is expected? Why are you still using deprecated `mysql_*` functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check `array_key_exists()` or similar, not `in_array()` since you are comparing keys.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will accept this in 6 minutes when it permits me to do so. I will have to go back and read over these to remember the difference in the future.